# android - ProgressBar is not working in HTC ICS

Tags: android, android-progressbar

ProgressBar view is working fine in htc wild fire s(2.1). But in case of Htc one V(4.1) it's not working properly means progressbar is not showing. please can anyone help me.

```
Code

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
< LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="180dip"              
  android:layout_height="80dip" 
  android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
  android:background="@drawable/findinggifts"
  >


  < ProgressBar 
  android:id="@+id/progress"         
  style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"       
  android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
  android:paddingTop="45dip"
  /> 



</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Try adjusting the background behind the `ProgressBar` to see if it is a question of contrast between the new `ProgressBar` images and your current background.